# Search function is not returning result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, keyboard-events

***Functionality:***

User is able to do a search on image source and when click search, will return the correct image source.

***What I have done:***

Have created a Search input box and when user clicks on the input box, an onscreen keyboard will be displayed (fade in). User will get to click on the keyboard to input the character. Once done, user can either click on the Search button to begin Search or the search will begin as the characters are written into the text search box.

Have attached the code for your perusal:

```js
var shift = false,
  capslock = false;
var $write;
var slideDuration = 1200;
$(function() {
  $("#SearchField").focus(function() {
    $write = $('#SearchField');
    $("#keyboard").show();
  });

  //Search Image Brand Function
  $("#SearchField").keyup(function() {
    var userInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    console.log("here");

    $("#list img").each(function() {

      $this = $(this),
        imageName = $this.attr('src').split('/'); // Split src by '/'

      // Get last part (filename)
      imageName = imageName.pop();

      // Remove extension
      imageName = imageName.split('.')[0];

      // Show images with matching filename
      $this.toggle(imageName.indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
    });
  });
});

$("#SearchField").click(function() {
    $('#SearchKeyBoard').fadeIn({
      duration: slideDuration,
      queue: false,
      complete: function() {
        $('#Search_keyboard li').off('click').on('click', function() {
          console.log("click");
          idleTime = 0;

          var $this = $(this),
            character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable
          console.log(character);
          // Shift keys
          if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
            $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
            $('.symbol span').toggle();

            shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
            capslock = false;
            return false;
          }

          // Caps lock
          if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
            $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
            capslock = true;
            return false;
          }

          // Delete
          if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
            var html = $write.val();

            $write.val(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
            return false;
          }

          // Clear
          if ($this.hasClass('clear')) {
            var html = $write.val();

            $write.val("");
            return false;
          }

          // Special characters
          if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
          if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
          if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
          if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

          // Uppercase letter
          if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

          // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
          if (shift === true) {
            $('.symbol span').toggle();
            if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

            shift = false;
          }
          // Add the character
          $write.val($write.val() + character);
        });
      }
    });
  })
  //Search Image Brand Function

function Search() {
  //var userInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  console.log("here");

  $("#list img").each(function() {

    $this = $(this),
      imageName = $this.attr('src').split('/'); // Split src by '/'

    // Get last part (filename)
    imageName = imageName.pop();

    // Remove extension
    imageName = imageName.split('.')[0];

    // Show images with matching filename
    $this.toggle(imageName.indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Keyboard CSS*/

.keyboard {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.keyboard li {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2 2 2 2;
  width: 65px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.capslock,
.tab,
.left-shift {
  clear: left;
}
.keyboard .tab,
.keyboard .delete {
  width: 165px;
}
.keyboard .capslock {
  width: 101px;
}
.keyboard .return {
  width: 101px;
}
.keyboard .left-shift {
  width: 165px;
}
.keyboard .right-shift {
  width: 165px;
}
.lastitem {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.keyboard .space {
  clear: left;
  width: 685px;
}
.on {
  display: none;
}
.keyboard li:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#Search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 750px;
  left: 800px;
  z-index: 100;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="Vivo_ChooseBrand" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display:none; z-index=3; top:0px; left:0px;">
  <input type="text" id="SearchField" style="position:absolute; top:190px; left:660px; height:40px; width:600px; outline=0px; border: 0; font-size:25px; font-family:'CenturyGothic'; background: transparent; z-index=4;" src="lib/VivoCity/img/transparent.png">
  <div class="Container">
    <div id="list" class="innerScroll">
      <!--1st Row-->
      <img id="Brand_1" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" data-brand="1">
      <img id="Brand_2" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" data-brand="2">
      <img id="Brand_3" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:650px; border:0px;" data-brand="3">
      <img id="Brand_4" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:965px; border:0px;" data-brand="4">

      <!--2nd Row-->
      <img id="Brand_5" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('5');">
      <img id="Brand_6" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('6');">
      <img id="Brand_7" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('7');">
      <img id="Brand_8" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('8');">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="SearchKeyBoard" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display:none; top:0px; left:0px; z-index=4;">

  <ul class="keyboard" id="Search_keyboard" style="z-index:19; position:absolute;left:580px; top: 400px; color: #000000;">
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">0</span></li></font>

    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter" style="clear: left;">q</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">w</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">e</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">r</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">t</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">y</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">u</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">i</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">o</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter lastitem">p</li></font>

    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter" style="clear: left;">a</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">s</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">d</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">f</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">g</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">h</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">j</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">k</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">l</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter lastitem">z</li></font>

    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter" style="clear: left;">x</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">c</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">v</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">b</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">n</li></fint>
                <font face ="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">m</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">(</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">)</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">@</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">-</span></li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="clear" style=" clear: left; width: 330px;">Clear</li></font>
    <font face="CenturyGothic"> <li class="delete lastitem" style="width: 349px;">Backspace</li></font>

    <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="space lastitem">Space &nbsp;</li></font>
  </ul>
  <button id="Search" onclick="Search()">
  </button>
</div>
```

***Issue:***

At this point in time, when user inputs the character from the onscreen keyboard, the auto-search function is not being called from `$("#SearchField").keyup(function(){..}` the following method. Secondly, when I click on the Search button, the search function is not being called as well.

Hence, what I do need is that when user input the char from onscreen keyboard, the search function is being called and the searched image is being displayed in the list.

Please help Thank you.

Comment: does it work the answer?

Comment: @user2352577L, I am sorry. I have tried but the search is still not returning any result..pls see the updated code

Comment: You can't show keyboard with this `#keyboard` because in html it a class attribute value not id and where is the code to append value to Text Box when keyboard item is clicked?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 what do you mean?  value to textbox when keyboard item is clicked is declared at `$(function() {
  $("#SearchField").focus(function() {
    $write = $('#SearchField');
    $("#keyboard").show();
  });....});` and  the val is is declared at keyboard.click function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

> Just after adding character **trigger keyup event manually** *currently it's not triggering because you are updating value using JavaScript not keyboard*.

You added character here to textbox($write):

```
// Add the character
/* just after adding character trigger kayup event manually here */
$write.val($write.val() + character).trigger('keyup');
```

Comment: great!! thanks!! So what is being said and so far from other comments that I have understood is that the keyup function is more for the physical keyboard rather than for the javascript keyboard. Therefore, a javascript keyboard will not be able to trigger the keyup event on its on. Hence to trigger the keyup event, will have to trigger it every time a value is added into the textbox via the javascript keyboard

Comment: Yes it does, have accepted, can't upvote though. thanks

Answer (score -2):

You have to use event listener. Try:

```
$('body').on('keyup','#SearchField',function(){
//do the next
});
```

Comment: Does that mean, the button `onclick= "Search()"` is not needed? furthermore, in your comment of `//Do next`, that is the part where I input in the search method call that I have?

Comment: am still not getting it though I have used the event listener.

Comment: You have to use event listeners after you call THE first event. Maybe you had to save all the code since your fadein ON a function with Javascript And call it in //do_something